# What's a tcpdump one-liner to dump a TCP stream that matches a given substring?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, tcpdump

Is there a quick tcpdump one-liner to print out a TCP stream that matches a particular substring -- or, if that's not easy, how about printing out just the single TCP *packet* that matches the substring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option is to use [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) rather than tcpdump. Ngrep is designed to do exactly what you're after.